# SQL, All Tables, Some special Columns, First NOT NULL Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to see a list of the first NOT NULL Value of all Columns starting with 'FK_%' (for foreign key) for all of the tables in the database.

It should look like this

```
SELECT c.name as Columnname, t.name as tablename
FROM sys.syscolumns c JOIN sys.tables t on c.id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name like 'FK_%'
```

just with a third column with the first NOT NULL value of the column in the table.
The columnnames are not unique.

I tried to combine it with this code for getting the row values but I failed.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
  FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sql)
```

Can you help me here to get a result like:

```
ID, Columnname, tablename, Value (First not null value)
Erik
```

Table: Account

```
ID, Date,       FK_Kst,   FK_Lst,   text,  number,  creator, creating_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,  2019-10-10, **3467**, NULL,     text1, number1, EL,      2019-12-13
2,  2019-10-11, NULL,     **6432**, text2, number2, EL,      2019-12-13
3,  2019-11-10, 3567,     5452,     text3, number3, EL,      2019-12-13
```

Table: Costobject

```
ID, FK_KK,    FK_AD,    PK_ID, text,  number,  creator
------------------------------------------------------
1,  NULL,     NULL,     4544,  text1, number1, EL
2,  **3452**, NULL,     4234,  text2, number2, EL
3,  3422,     **6545**, 4134,  text3, number3, EL
```

Result:

- All Columns with "FK_%"
- Tablenames
- first value of the rows (NOT NULL)

```
    columnname, tablename,  value
    -----------------------------
    FK_Kst,     Account,    3467
    FK_Lst,     Account,    6432
    FK_KK,      Costobject, 3452
    FK_AD,      Costobject, 6545
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Also, first based on what sort order?

Comment: sort order doesent madder in this case. Column "Value" just has the be filled.

Comment: Do you just need *any* not null value for any column? This is a simpler problem, since you will not need to take sorting into account.
Basically you should do a `select max(FK_Kst) FK_Kst,max(FK_Lst) FK_Lst ... from table`to get a any non null values, then pivot that result to your target format - look at dynamic pivot examples.

Comment: yes, any not null value is enough.
I don't know how.. there are more thaan 100 tables and more than 1000 'FK_%' columns.

Answer (score 0):

This generates a select statement for a table, slects max values for each columns, and pivots the result long format

```
DECLARE @tableschema VARCHAR(100) = <SCHEMA>
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(100) = <TABLE>
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @SQL='select 
Case n ' +
    STRING_AGG(CAST('when ' + CAST(c.ORDINAL_POSITION AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' then ''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '''' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION)
    + ' end columnname'
    + ',''[' + @tableschema + '].[' + @tablename + ']'' as tablename'
    + ',Case n ' +
    STRING_AGG(CAST('when ' + CAST(c.ORDINAL_POSITION AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' then cast([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] as varchar(max))' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION)
    + ' end [value]
from '
    +
    '(select ' +
    STRING_AGG(CAST(
    'max([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']) [' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION)
    + ' from [' + @tableschema + '].[' + @tablename + ']) m
' +
    'cross join (values' + STRING_AGG('(' + CAST(c.ORDINAL_POSITION AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION)
    + ') a(n)'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableschema
AND c.TABLE_NAME = @tablename
AND LEFT(c.COLUMN_NAME,3)='FK_'

SELECT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

If you change it by wrapping it in a stored procedure perhaps, then you could call it once for each table.
The downside is that it scans all rows in the table, so if you have large tables, its not efficient, since you just want one not null value

Comment: Hi Søren Kongstad,

I'm not getting it done.
Do you can think of another workaround instead of using a procedure?

Maybe 2 seperate (temp) tables and then using a Join with the combination of table and columnname?

First table like:
 
SELECT c.name as Columnname, t.name as tablename
FROM sys.syscolumns c JOIN sys.tables t on c.id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name like 'FK_%'

second table:
all combinations of table one in columns or rows 
joining on this tables and  columns 
getting one value and 
union them?

Thanks for any help